# How to add deprecation notice to multiple destructured variables?

Tags: javascript, jsdoc

I need to add deprecation notice to multiple (up to 100) variables using JSDoc. Is it possible to do so without repeating the same notice 100 times?

My code looks like this:

```
/**
* @deprecated
* Those colors are deprecated
*/
export const {color1, color2, color3 /* more here */} = mainColors
```

But it doesn't work. I can still import those variables and IDE gives no warning.

Comment: If you have that many exports, you'll need that many deprecations.

Comment: Is it possible to deprecate the entire module?